# Do you know any examples of using CSS 3D Transforms in the wilds?

Tags: css, css-transforms

Do you know any examples of using CSS 3D Transforms in the wilds but 
http://2012.beercamp.com/ and http://acko.net/ ?

Answer (score 1):

I made a site a while back that can be found here: http://www.southamptontaxis.org/our-partners/ .

I did a little write up halfway down http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/flip/ .

Here's another one from the comments on my site: http://www.deirdremoore.com/bragbook.shtml